# Imp long mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query and want to extend it. how can I only show results from the column descri called "house" or "company"

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.descri
FROM
  predb AS a
  LEFT JOIN housedb AS b
    ON a.name = b.name
WHERE b.name IS NULL
  AND a.ctime BETWEEN 172800 AND 1583183053
```

unfortunately I don't know where I have to insert it so that the query is correct

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: add `AND a.descri IN ('house','company')`

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN function: 
syntax example :

```
 where descri IN('house','company')
```